# Is this a safe way of keeping command prompt open?

Tags: c#, c++, command-prompt

I have read many posts on how to keep command prompts open and most answers I found was to either add something like SYSTEM("PAUSE"), or getchar(), Console.ReadLine(), (Depending C# or C++). Now one thing I was wondering is it okay if I have at the end of main

```
while(true) { Console.ReadLine(); }
```

I just don't want it to close if someone presses an character or something. Is this a safe way or no?

Comment: What do you mean by "safe"?

Comment: Will this potentially lead to some problem in lets say in some other environment? Lets say maybe embedded systems? And also, just curious why is there no option to disable it from disappearing?

Comment: Why would you *not* want the terminal to close when the program is done, if the terminal was only opened to run the program?  If you want it to persist, why don't you just a) open the terminal. 2) launch the program from the commandline and wait for it to terminate 3) stare at your persistent terminal for as long as you like.  ??   Programs *can* be run in other ways than just "clickity clicking them" you know...

Comment: I am trying to run programs to see if certain outputs are displayed, for instance using the "Poor mans way" of debugging using print statements instead of the debugger?

Comment: What do you mean with "command prompt open" ???  what do you exactly want to do with the program input/output through stdin/stdout.  This is not a language related question, but better an operating system dependient one (depending on the environment, you can have no console input output ---think on a batch processing environment, for example)

Comment: Run your code from the command prompt directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use an infinite loop you should probably have an escape hatch. For instance

```
while(true) {
string input = Console.ReadLine();

if (input == "quit")
break;
}
```

Comment: Never thought of that, an escape hatch seems like a great solution. Also is there a reason why break; is used over something like return -1;?

Comment: the break; exits the infinite loop and executes whatever code exists after the loop. If there is no more code after the loop it simply terminates itself. In this case return -1; will work in the same way

Comment: Thank you great explanation, really appreciate it!

Comment: You are welcome. Feel free to mark my answer as accepted if you think it answered your question :)